# Split one CSS file into multiple or extract contents after a certain comment

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

How can I split a CSS file into two by a custom condition, that means is there a way to split one CSV file after certain comments in the CSS file?

`.one{`
`background-color: black;`
`}`

`.two{`
`background-color: yellow;`
`}`

`/** end of css1 **/`

`.three{`
`background-color: red;`
`}`

`.four{`
`background-color: green;`
`}`

now I'd like to copy only contents after the comment

```
/** end of css1 **/
```

one new file should have only

`.three{`
`background-color: red;`
`}`

`.four{`
`background-color: green;`
`}`

Comment: What makes you think that such thing is possible ?